# Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I get the Error

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.androidbuch.activiti/de.androidbuch.activiti.task.Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
```

when I switch via the portrait and the landscape mode. I'm using fragments. My xml is:

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"/> 

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragmentDetails"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              class="de.androidbuch.activiti.task.TaskDetailsFragment"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

If I switch via landscape and portrait mode everything works fine. But when I click on my fragment (and I can see my fragment) and then switch to the other mode I get the error. Any idea how I can solve it? Found some answers here but none of these helped me out...

```
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         
ComponentInfo{de.androidbuch.activiti/de.androidbuch.activiti.task.Activity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3097)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:997)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3998)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1771)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at de.androidbuch.activiti.task.TaskActivity.onCreate(TaskActivity.java:83)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
06-21 14:55:05.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7636):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Are you keeping separate layout files in your layout and layout-land folders?

Comment: Can you provide the full error log, including the lines *after* "Unable to start activity..."

Comment: @Nathan Fig: yes I do.. but getting the errors..

Comment: @Dave: here you go.. any idea?

Comment: Need landscape layout code, and also helpful would be your calls to setContentView and also how you are firing off activity in portrait mode as I'm assuming you are. At the moment there doesn't seem to be enough information. Looking at FragmentLayout example in API demos may help you as it sounds like you are doing something similar.

Comment: Refer this link you will get an idea..

[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16271463/3630904

Comment: this link solved this exact same problem for us:
[here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532017/viewpagerindicator-library-doesnt-work-in-4-4)

Comment: for Android beginners.  note that **very simply, this can be caused by** having in your XML **<YourSpecialView rather than <com.blah.blah.YourSpecialView** - sometimes it is that simple.

Comment: use framelayout instead of fragment.

Comment: [I think this issue is solved here at least for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60597670/9513504)

Comment: 44 "answers" y'all got to be kidding me

Answer (score 133):

As hdemirchian said, make sure to use:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And also make sure that the Activity that is using the fragment(s) extends `FragmentActivity` instead of the regular `Activity`,

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

to get the `FragmentActivity` class.

Comment: This got upvoted a lot, but for me it crashes when resuming the app, and I am already using v4 Fragment and v4 FrsgmentActivity - to be more precise AppCompatActivity.

Comment: This is no solution. import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; does not change anything. Actually it is even unused and unneeded import.

Comment: Thanks, a side note is that AppCompatActivity is a descendant of FragmentActivity.

Comment: but i am using dagger fragment , and dagger fragment always extend fragment not fragment activity

Answer (score 108):

The exception `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: #... Error inflating class fragment` might happen if you manipulate with `getActivity()` inside your fragment before `onActivityCreated()` get called. In such case you receive a wrong activity reference and can't rely on that.

For instance the next pattern is wrong:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);

    Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...); - another problem: button is null

    return view;
}
```

Correct pattern #1

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...);

    return view;
}
```

Correct pattern #2

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: @MaximKorobov You can call `getActivity()` inside `onActivityCreated()` or in any subsequent lifecycle method, but before `onDestroyView()`.

Comment: I'd love to find out more about this, I'm getting a sporadic crash and I think this might be the problem. Although most of the time the code works fine so it's hard to know

Comment: Pattern 2 might have solved it for me. Fingers crossed. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 55):

Make sure your `Activity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: [Note: FragmentActivity is a special activity provided in the Support Library to handle fragments on system versions older than API level 11. If the lowest system version you support is API level 11 or higher, then you can use a regular Activity.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Comment: @RobinF AppCompatActivity extends itself FragmentActivity

Answer (score 46):

I had the same error. I was digging all day long, don't know but I think I tried ~25 solutions on this problem. None worked until at 2AM I found out that I was missing this line at apps manifest xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

That line was inside `<application>` tag. I really hope this helps for someone.
GL.

Comment: Explain what is going on please. What is the benefit of this line?

Comment: Thanks, Save my day. Each sample of using Google map on android work differently, I wonder if there is a standard.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was the order of super.onCreate and setContentView within the FragmentActivity

Following order works fine:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fc_activity_list_profiles);
```

Comment: In a JAVA method, `super` must always be called at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert it is not always the case that `super.method()` must be called first. It depends on what the super class's method does. In the case of `FragmentActivity` it does some initialization needed to make `setContentView` work properly. However in another method (say `onKeyUp`) you may want to conditionally do some work with the action, but fallback onto `super.onKeyUp` in which case you will very likely want to call `super.onKeyUp` at the very end of the function.

Comment: It is probably also worth noting that `super()` (the superclass's constructor) must be the first function called in any child classes constructor, however calling it is not necessarily mandatory (it would depend entirely on the class being extended).

Answer (score 19):

### Fragments cannot be nested in XML

Learnt this the hard way - if you nest an XML layout based `<fragment>` tag inside a (potentially) dynamically loaded fragment from `FragmentManager`, then you start to get weird errors, trying to inflate your fragment xml.

Turns out, that this is *not* supported - it will work fine if you do this through purely the `FragmentManager` approach.

I was getting this problem because I was trying load a fragment inside a `<DrawerLayout>` from xml, and this was causing a crash in the `onCreateView()` method when I popped the back stack.

Comment: Is this still not supported? As of `appcompat-v7:23.3.0`

Comment: yes I am nesting fragment inside xml . I will look into that.

Comment: But there exists solutions/hacks for the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695397/860488

Comment: See the note at the end of this section for confirmation: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: not sure why the solution is SO simple. for me, just replacing `<fragment>` with `<frameLayout>` worked. I'm still figuring it out.  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167009/5477548

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem as you are facing.
None of the tips on top helped me.
Later, I found that all I had to do is fix my imports from:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: You are awesome! My problem was opposite - the Fragment wizard imports android.support.v4.app.Fragment by default. And my main activity extends android.app.Activity.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried:

```
 <fragment
            android:name="de.androidbuch.activiti.task.TaskDetailsFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: You've shown us 1 xml file, but you should have 2 one in /layout/ and one in layout-land/

Answer (score 12):

Make sure there is no exception raised in the onCreateView method of the fragment. If any exception is raised in this method, logcat won't show exact details of the exception, instead it always shows the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

Comment: Just to add what Lei is saying is, put try catch around code inside your oncreateview and find out actual root cause. Thanks Lei!

Answer (score 6):

If your `TaskDetailsFragment` extending `android.app.Fragment`, do change in  `onCreateView()`.

Return your **view** which you want to show in the Fragment or convert your Layout to view by using **LayoutInflater** and return it.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    return mainview;
}
```

Hope this works. :)

Answer (score 6):

Check you class path, this could be the view inflator could not find your class definition as defined in your xml
class="de.androidbuch.activiti.task.TaskDetailsFragment"
the above path could be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I was receiving this error for different reasons.

Steps to reproduce:

~> My issue was that I created a brand new blank application.

~> I then generated a custom fragment from the File ~> New File Menu.

~> Proceeded to customize the fragment by adding layouts and buttons etc.

~> Referenced the new custom fragment in the auto generated activity_my.xml that was generated for me when creating the application. Doing this allowed the XML to generate the objects for me.

Heres is the catch when generating the custom fragment via File ~> New File Menu it auto generates an interface function stub and places it at the bottom of the fragment class file.

This means that your MyActivity class must implement this interface. If it does not then the the above error occurs only when referencing the fragment from xml. By removing the reference for the Fragment in the XML completely, and creating the fragment through code in the MyActivity.java class file Logcat generates a more concise error explaining the issue in detail and complaining about the interface. This is demonstrated in the Project Template Activity+Fragment. Although, <~that Project Template does not generate the interface stub.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was after scrolling in the stack trace i found im missing the permission for android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

after adding this permission it was fixed

Comment: Not to self: "scroll through the *entire* stack trace. Thank you @Gil.

Answer (score 4):

If you have separate layout files for portrait and landscape modes and are getting an inflation error whenever you change orientation after clicking an item, there is most likely a discrepancy between your layout files.

When you get the error, is it only when you click the item in landscape mode or only in portrait mode or both? Does your TaskDetailsFragment activity use a layout file that could have discrepancies between landscape and portrait modes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. well I only have a fragment in the landscape mode and not in the portrait mode. So I can click only in the landscape mode to see the fragment. And after I switch again to the landscape mode I get this error...

Comment: That's almost certainly the problem then- you have a view in portrait mode that can't be found in landscape mode. Does adding the fragment to landscape fix the issue?

Comment: You can have views that don't exist in both files -- that's the whole point of having separate -land and -port layouts. However, check the ids-- I had the id missing in my portrait file and was getting this error when switching.

Answer (score 4):

If you are adding `Fragment` statically that is, in xml, then you might have missed to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your `Activity` class. Then the interface implementation would solve the problem. If you are adding `Fragment` dynamically, that is, in java class then this is not the solution. Because IDE itself will not allow you to proceed without implementing required interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change anything and go with "**fragment**" tag

do this,

```
<fragment
 android:visibility="gone" (Visibility will not work, just helps in removing frag from xml viewer)(If you want the visibility to be gone make it in your fragment root element visibility=gone)
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.example.YOUR_FRAGMENT" (This is important)
 />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView instead of fragment. Here is a example:

```
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView 
          android:id="@+id/fragmentDetails"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          class="de.androidbuch.activiti.task.TaskDetailsFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions mentioned above helped me. In the log I could find the detail of the exception as mentioned below:

```
06-19 16:20:37.885: E/AndroidRuntime(23973): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that /meta-data/ android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/ is in the application element of AndroidManifest.xml.
```

I did this and my code was working!

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCl1yGPZ3mpxxxxxxxAz2R-t7zcWVzrHUL9k"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem in this case was a simple instance of having a dumb null pointer exception in one of my methods that was being invoked later in the lifecycle. This was causing the "Error inflating class fragment" exception for me. In short, please remember to check the further down the exception stack trace for a possible cause.

Once I resolved the null pointer exception, my fragment loaded fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error type, where exactly the same error message in logcat was displayed. I needed to make changes in the Java Build Path located under `Project->Properties`. I had included Google Maps related libraries like `android-support-v4.jar` and `google-play-services.jar`; however I was missing including these on the `'Build class path'` in the `'Order and Export'` option menu. Maybe the error lies here.

Try including libraries to the build class path.

The order of which the classes are built might also trigger the error, so my advice is also to try to rearrange the order of the building path. The error disappeared when I used the following order: `'my_project_name/src'->'my_project_name/gen'->'Android Private Libraries'`. The last unit contains the jar files mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when using a ListFragment but the list view id was listView1 instead of list.

'Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list''

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inherit the **AppCompatActivity**, then you can do something like this-
In the activity xml, use a **FrameLayout** like this-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/result_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress_frame"/>
```

and in the activity `onCreate`-

```
final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.result_fragment, fphResultActivityFragment, "result fragment");
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Thanks this helped.  Not sure why I was able to use <fragment> in my layout successfully in other apps I've worked on, but it wasn't working here!

Comment: just note this can work but this is usually for dynamic fragments not static

Answer (score 2):

I added an id to my fragment that's it everything works fine. Before this, I changed the manifests file as mentioned above but didn't solve my error. When you see error try to read it fully you'll get to know why there is an error. In my case, in the middle of the error trace, it was shown that the fragment id is missing.

```
<fragment
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.example.mydemofragmentapp.FoodListFragment"
       android:id="@+id/none"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a possible answer. So here we go.

My situation is, I change my project from Java to Kotlin, and then add Navigation Component. After migrating to Kotlin, then I add the `nav_graph.xml`. But, after try running the app, I got an *inflating error*. After checking further and comparing to other projects, turn out My `nav_graph.xml` did not have `app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment"`. After adding `app:startDestination`, the error went away and my project runs just fine with no error.

*nav_graph.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="fragment.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
</navigation>
```

So, don't forget the `app:startDestination`.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file just use a  instead of the  tag.
The inflater tries to create an  android.app.Fragment from  which will fail on API < 10.
So you need to create a view group of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that u have used this one

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBEwmfL0GaZmdVqdTxxxxxxxx-rVgvY" />
```

not this..

```
<meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
          android:value="AIzaSyBEwmfL0GaZmdVqdTCvxxxxxxx-rVgvY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same error. The reason for mine was the visibility of my fragment class. It was set to default, should be public.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the fragment's `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods? I had exactly same exception which was caused by an exception in the fragment `onCreate` method, when I fixed that problem it fixed the *Error inflating class fragment.*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; after running the [AdMob example](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start), I tried to insert Ads in my app, causing this error:

```
01-02 16:48:51.269    8199-8199/it.dndc.BreathPlot E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
```

The solution is: you cannot insert the fragment for an Ad into a ListActivity.
Instead, I could add it to a FragmentActivity and to an ActionBarActivity without any problem.

My suggestion is: start from the AdMob example and add into it your existing app: I would have saved a lot of time !!!

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error in android studio the problem was that my fragment had a relative layout while the code on the OnCreateView function was

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

is your code doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Activity extends FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but my issue was that my fragment did not have an id in the xml layout of the parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

After one day struggle i found some scenario check may be you are facing same,

> If everything is woking same as google code then please check manifest file in my case i added geo key and map key that's why exception occurs,

**Note - do not add two keys in manifest file remove map key**

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

above code and add this code.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/auto_location"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use obfuscation with Navigation component you need to exclude android's fragment and your args.
Add these lines to your proguard-rules files:

```js
# Exclude the fragments and argType for navigation component.
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
-keep class com.safetonet.presentation.features.parent.adddevice.model.PresentableAddDeviceData
```

Answer (score 1):

### I did not have the `androidx.fragment:fragment` dependency.

You can get the latest version from the Jetpack/ AndroidX [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment):

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    // Testing Fragments in Isolation
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fragment is a List Fragment then the activity which uses that fragment must implement the `onFragmentInteraction` interface.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
...
android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
...
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
class *.HomeFragment has no zero argument constructor
...
```

After I added the empty constructor, it's resolved.

```
public HomeFragment() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple approach

If you use `<fragment>` in your xml then you must provide `name` attribute i.e;

```
      <fragment 
        android:name='path.to.your.fragment
        />`
```

which will initialise your fragment and you don't need to do it from java.

If you want to use Java approach to add fragment then, use any layout like

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
 />
```

and use this container for your fragment

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have put your google-services.json on your respective folder and oviously add

```
<meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

in your manifest file. Check your gradle with
 "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'"

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #31: Duplicate id 0x7f09006d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.example.eduardf.audit.DateTime
```

In my case, the error occurred when re-opening the DialogFragment with a Fragment.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_black_edit_24px"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_date"
            android:name="com.example.eduardf.audit.DateTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_date_time" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

DailogFragment stores the fragment after the first inflate.
To prevent this from happening, I forcibly deleted the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView () {
    if (!(afterRotate || getActivity() == null)) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        final Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_date);
        if (fragment != null)
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Also had to take care of unnecessary removal of the fragment, for example, when you rotate the screen.

```
private boolean afterRotate = false;
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    afterRotate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, refactored code caused the problem. I moved a fragment into a new package and one of the references in the xml file caused the bug. So inspect your code very well

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I am adding Google maps API key in the value folder! move it to `src/debug/res/values/sensitive_keys.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem started to happen after the target activity movement.
The reason was in Android databinding - previously it generated intermediate classes and after activities classes movements these intermediate files remained.
Cleaning of the project helped.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when start using Hilt.
**If you are using Hilt** , sure that you declare your appliction class  in your AndroidManifest.xml file, in the `<application.../>`tag  , and  **annotate your application class with @HiltAndroidApp**, and if you are use **fragment**, annotate your **host activity by @AndroidEntryPoint**

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the errors you could get If your activity is not registered on the manifest. Check and ensure that your activity is registered on the manifest, that could be the possible cause of your error.

Comment: Would you like trying to rephrase this into something which gives more an impression of being a helpful answer and less of "Me too." post? I think it is possible.

Answer (score -10):

Adding this to manifest solved my problem

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Absolutely not related to the main problem here.