# android google map v2 and fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I can't understand why my application can't work.

I saw this post: [Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)

but it don't works for me.

I have the error :Error infaltion the class fragment

This is my java code:

```
package ant.junior.xbonnel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class ReferentMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_referent_map);
}
}
```

My xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ReferentMapActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ant.junior.xbonnel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxx"/>

     <permission
          android:name="ant.junior.xbonnel.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="ant.junior.xbonnel.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ant.junior.xbonnel.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ant.junior.xbonnel.ReferentIdentificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_referent_identification" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ant.junior.xbonnel.ReferentMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_referent_map" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe you have got badly registrate API key on the http://code.google.com/apis/console or you don't have imported Google play services library in your project. I saw your code and I think that everything is alright.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem changing my meta-data place.

Comment: Hey Bro I'm having the same issue. Can you help me out with my mine too. Here's my post :-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820339/issue-with-google-maps-android-api-v2