# Issue with Google Maps Android Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been trying to implement a sample application in order to study the working of Google maps API. I have been struck with the configuration itself. I can't seem to run the application.

Here's my code at Github :-

https://github.com/siva54/SampleMapApplication

And here's my logcat :-

```
02-11 15:09:07.492: I/Process(10080): Sending signal. PID: 10080 SIG: 9
02-11 15:09:17.012: E/dalvikvm(10364): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions', referenced from method     com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.setUpMap
02-11 15:09:17.012: W/dalvikvm(10364): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 455 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions;) in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;
02-11 15:09:17.012: D/dalvikvm(10364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0004
02-11 15:09:17.012: E/dalvikvm(10364): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded
02-11 15:09:17.012: W/dalvikvm(10364): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 452 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;
02-11 15:09:17.012: D/dalvikvm(10364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
02-11 15:09:17.012: D/dalvikvm(10364): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0cd0 at 0x06 in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;.setUpMap
02-11 15:09:17.022: D/dalvikvm(10364): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0ccf at 0x0b in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;.setUpMap
02-11 15:09:17.072: D/AndroidRuntime(10364): Shutting down VM
02-11 15:09:17.072: W/dalvikvm(10364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e02930)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.gasapplication/com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    ... 11 more
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    ... 21 more
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.myapp.gasapplication-1.apk
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
02-11 15:09:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10364):    ... 24 more
02-11 15:10:58.032: E/dalvikvm(10887): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions', referenced from method com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.setUpMap
02-11 15:10:58.032: W/dalvikvm(10887): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 455 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions;) in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;
02-11 15:10:58.032: D/dalvikvm(10887): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0004
02-11 15:10:58.032: E/dalvikvm(10887): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded
02-11 15:10:58.032: W/dalvikvm(10887): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 452 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;
02-11 15:10:58.032: D/dalvikvm(10887): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
02-11 15:10:58.032: D/dalvikvm(10887): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0cd0 at 0x06 in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;.setUpMap
02-11 15:10:58.032: D/dalvikvm(10887): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0ccf at 0x0b in Lcom/myapp/gasapplication/MainActivity;.setUpMap
02-11 15:10:58.092: D/AndroidRuntime(10887): Shutting down VM
02-11 15:10:58.092: W/dalvikvm(10887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e02930)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.gasapplication/com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at com.myapp.gasapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    ... 11 more
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    ... 21 more
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.myapp.gasapplication-2.apk
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at     dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
02-11 15:10:58.092: E/AndroidRuntime(10887):    ... 24 more
```

Would you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you create your project with google and not android ??

Comment: I've created my project with the android. And during the development I've executed it with both Android and Android+Google apks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Problem. The issue occurred because even though I i referenced the google play library, The reference is not considered by eclipse and it was shown by a cross mark. I have resolved that with the help of the following stackoverflow post:-

[In eclipse, unable to reference an android library project in another android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not finding the Google Maps classes at runtime. Are you running this on a device or an emulator because you can't use Google Maps v2 on an emulator at this time.

If you are running on a device then make sure you have Google Play Services installed. It contains the runtime for Google Maps v2.

Comment: Hey Damian. I'm running it on my nexus 7. I've just now checked with play.google and it reports that google play services is installed.