# import lib google.android.gms "Could not find class" after updating sdk and google-api

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

I use google-play-services_lib for one project but after upgrading the google api and sdk,

I get these errors :

```
05-21 01:57:55.813: E/dalvikvm(22721): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method com.eloges.services.GeoLocService$2.onLocationChanged
```

or this :

```
05-21 01:57:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(22721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 01:57:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(22721): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptionsCreator
```

I read this questions : [Issue with Google Maps Android Api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820339/issue-with-google-maps-android-api-v2)

but, I tested "google-play-services_lib" on another project and I don't have these errors...

So I concluded that, my error come from my project.

I copied and imported again my project, with right click(Properties>Library >Add etc....) like on another project where it works... but I still have these errors where it can come from?

to "solve" my problem, I created a new project and I copied my java files and xml files.

If someone already had this problem without creating a new project like me..., I'm interested in the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on the project, under `Build Path`, select `Configure Build Path`, select the `Order and Export` tab and check the relevant lib. Had the same issue with the support library today.

Comment: thank you very much , it was a problem of order of libs. I had not seen

Comment: Thank you, thank you. This had been stumping me for days now.