# Why is the fragment view causing an android app to fail in the eclipse emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) Google demo, and my app fails when I include the fragment view. The eclipse emulator produces a dialog stating that the app unexpectedly closed.

The code does nothing meaningful at all, and it cannot be the problem because when I run it without the fragment in activity_main.xml, it works fine.

Code:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

I cannot copy the xml, but it is the default blank "activity_main" xml file (with the RelativeLayout root) with the fragment added in, inside the RelativeLayout parent, exactly as in the demo, only without the re-copied xml version tag (which is identical to the one already there).

When I remove the fragment, it runs fine.

What am I doing to make the fragment class unusable?

**Update: here is the logcat**

```
04-25 01:35:42.202: D/AndroidRuntime(441): Shutting down VM

04-25 01:35:42.202: W/dalvikvm(441): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sikkemamap/com.example.sikkemamap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.example.sikkemamap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  ... 11 more

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sikkemamap-2.apk]

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)

04-25 01:35:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  ... 20 more

04-25 01:35:55.342: I/Process(441): Sending signal. PID: 441 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you post your LogCat trace so it might help diagnosing?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the trace there. I can't see it in comment. Perhaps too long

Comment: Yes, sorry... it is in the question now.

Comment: Search for `Error inflating class fragment`. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're extending `Activity` while targeting a pre-Honycomb (API level 11) device. For use of fragments on Gingerbread (API level 10) and lower you should be extending `FragmentActvity` instead.

Note: FragmentActivity is part of the Android Support Package, so make sure you have it imported in your project.

Comment: Thanks! I did finally realize that I had a minimum API that was too low... I solved the problem by setting the minimum API higher.

Comment: That's a possible way to solve it. If you still need to support lower API Levels I would recommend to use the FragmentActivity approach instead.