# Android:Inflate Exception in the class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I trying to use fragments in my code..After i clicked the fragments and tries to make screen orientation i got an error like below,...

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.frag/com.example.frag.Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
```

**My Xml**.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/> 
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" class="com.example.frag.MyFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the limited information you're giving, it looks like you're having the same problem addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment) post.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.,
I forgot to extend `FragmentActivity` istead of `Activity`..

It working now.

*Reference:*https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168223/1542636

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:name="com.example.frag.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/frag_layout" />
```

you must use android:name="fully qualified path". you have used class="".