# Orientation change Crash Application

Tags: android, orientation, fragment

I am using fragments and when i change the orientation the application crash.
Here is the log cat:

```
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse/com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-29 06:17:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse/com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
05-29 06:17:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-29 05:56:52.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse.SecondFragment did not create a view.
```

Here is my First_Test_Fragment class

```
package com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class First_Test_Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_test_fragment,container,false);
    Button btnLogin=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FirstFragment firstFragment=new FirstFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, firstFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

    });
    Button btnSignUp=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SignUp signup=new SignUp();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, signup);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();



        }

    });




    return view;
}



}



}
```

Here is my FirstFragment Class

```
package com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
EditText loginTestUser,loginTestPassword;
String userName,password,confirmpassword;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, container, false);


      loginTestUser=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
      loginTestPassword=    (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
       Button btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn); 

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"BttonLoginPressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // get The User name and Password
                 userName=loginTestUser.getText().toString();
                 password=loginTestPassword.getText().toString();

              // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                    String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                    // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                    if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Admin_Page.class);
                       //     getActivity().startActivity(intent);

                        Intent open=new Intent("com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse.ADMIN_PAGE");

                        getActivity().startActivity(open);
                        // startActivity(open);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            }

        });

   return view;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getActivity());
     loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
}
```

}

My Mainfest.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <activity  
       android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.bajraregistertesteclipse.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUp"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".Admin_Page">

     </activity>

</application>
```

Now my problem is Application crash when orientation change and When click to the button new activity Admin_Page should be initiatied but application crash.

Thank YOu in Advance!!!

Comment: The problem is most likely not in the manifest file, but in your layout file.

Comment: @Cornholio i can't figure out my problem.....

Comment: Your `SecondFragment` caused the issue and you posted the FirstFragment code, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

add this in your manifest file in your activity.

Comment: Do you know any other method to manage this problem?? If you are using  webview, css, etc related things, you cant use this method, because, you need to rearrange when orientation changes.

Comment: This is most likely going to crash after process death, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399

Answer (score 49):

```
<activity android:name=".SignUp"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Add this line to all your activities to avoid crash with orientation changes.
This will avoid the activity being loaded again and again on orientation changes.

---

For a little more information what you actually do with `configChanges` [here the link to the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config).

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.
>
> `Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.`

And how to handle `configuration changes` you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes).

Comment: ya thanks...why my application crash when i do Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Admin_Page.class);
               getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? I mean error in logcat

Comment: You are welcome. @Rohan Ale Please accept any answer that you find as correct so that this question wont remain unanswered.. :)

Comment: how can we destroy the previous activity. i.e when i sucessfully login then my new Activity start but when i press back button of moible i will directed towards my login page again which i want to destroy it. can you help me out ?

Comment: use finish(); before starting new activity

Comment: when i use finish(); ERROR: The method finish() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30833/discussion-between-mahesh-and-rohan-ale)

Comment: If it is a fragment then we need to use getActivity().finish(); otherwise activity_class_name.finish();

Comment: This is most likely going to crash after process death, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

You might also need to change your activity to extend FragmentActivity instead of just Activity. [More discussion Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

add this in all your activities in `Manifest`

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|locale|fontScale|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|navigation|touchscreen|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: It's useless to answer in this form. Explain what you mean and how that affects the app and how it solves the described problem.

Comment: This is the solution. You had to add this on your activity in manifest.

Comment: This is most likely going to crash after process death, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399

Answer (score 0):

There is another case I found If you use different XML for Portrait and Landscape. Then different root element or view may lead to crash for example --

My Portrait XML is --

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_page_back_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.thepsi.beintent.LoginPage"
    android:id="@+id/parent_login_page">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/linear_right_20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/linear_right_20dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beintent_logo" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_views_login_page"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/email_login"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/password_login"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:buttonTint="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_check_box_lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:text="@string/remember_me_login"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_rember_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/questionMark"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_check_box_lbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_question_mark"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password_login_page"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_rember_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_views_login_page"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_loginpage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_btn_selecter"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:onClick="LoginButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_login_page"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_page_button_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_loginpage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_btn_selecter"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:onClick="SignUpButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up_login_page"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_page_button_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:onClick="OnContactUsClicked"
            android:text="@string/contact_us"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/seperator"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:onClick="OnTermAndConditionsClicked"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Landscape xml is --

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_page_back_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.thepsi.beintent.LoginPage"
    android:id="@+id/parent_login_page">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login_page_back_gradient"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/parent_container"
        tools:context="com.thepsi.beintent.LoginPage">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/upper_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/linear_right_20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/linear_right_20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beintent_logo" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_views_login_page"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/email_login"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/password_login"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:buttonTint="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_check_box_lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:text="@string/remember_me_login"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_rember_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxLoginPage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background_red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/questionMark"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_check_box_lbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_question_mark"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password_login_page"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_rember_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_question_mark"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_views_login_page"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_loginpage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_btn_selecter"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:onClick="LoginButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_login_page"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_page_button_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_loginpage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/common_btn_selecter"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:onClick="SignUpButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up_login_page"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_page_button_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_contact_us"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upper_container"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:onClick="OnContactUsClicked"
            android:text="@string/contact_us"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_for_seperator"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/seperator"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:onClick="OnTermAndConditionsClicked"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Might be helpful to someone.