# Android app crashes when changed to landscape orientation

Tags: android

I am developing a simple android app with a TextView and ImageView on the launching page. When I rotate my phone to landscape mode, the app crashes. Though I see that the app is not killed, it just goes away and I can see that it is still running in Android Studio.
Following is my code:

**Content_main.xml -landscape mode**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.viral.myapplication2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ganpati_bappa_moraya"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        tools:context=".Blink"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/god_pic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Content_main.xml - for normal mode - portrait**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.viral.myapplication2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Ganpati Bappa Moraya !!!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:context=".Blink"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/god_pic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android_Manifest.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.viral.myapplication2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/god_pic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: read the error of the crash, or perhaps looka t what your activity is doing.

Comment: any errors on the logcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orientation change Crash Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806856/orientation-change-crash-application)

Comment: No error in logcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify AndroidManifest.xml file to this

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize".
```

`screenSize` property will take care about screen orientation change and activity life cycle will not call again.