# Passing Value from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity, kotlin-android-extensions

I have bottom navigation activity in my project and contain two fragments. I am trying to pass value from Activity--->FragmentOne and then From FragmentOne--->FragmentTwo. Any help is appreciated.

**Language Used**

```
Kotlin
```

**Expectation**

```
1)Pass value from Activity to Fragment
2)Send value from Fragment to Fragment
```

**Error**

```
Null Pointer Exception
```

**Code**

**Activity**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        var testName:String=intent.getStringExtra("name")
        println("TestCLLicked: $testName")
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        replaceFragment(TestFragmentOne.newInstance(),TestFragmentOne.TAG)
    }
```

**TestFragmentOne**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            var st:String=arguments!!.getString("name")
             println("TestCLLicked: $testName")
```

Comment: Please read how to use the newInstance patter https://medium.com/@azjkjensen/using-the-newinstance-pattern-in-kotlin-e40c1b4ba1ef

Comment: Use arguments bundle of Fragment before adding it

Comment: Oh BTW what does your newInstance do? You kinda left it out of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go many ways but given your current implementation (using a newInstance), I'd go with using your parent activity as a mediator, going like this:

1) Create a BaseFragment class which your TestFragmentOne and TestFragmentTwo will extend and in there hold a reference to your parent Activity (here named "MainActivity"):

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

     lateinit var ACTIVITY: MainActivity

     override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
         super.onAttach(context)
         ACTIVITY = context as MainActivity
     }
}
```

2) Then, in your Activity make sure you declare your variable as a field:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     var textVariable = "This to be read from the fragments"
     ...
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         textVariable = "I can also change this text"
         ...
     }
}
```

3) Then, from each fragment you can access your variable using the instance inherited from your BaseFragment:

```
 class TestFragmentOne : BaseFragment() {

      override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
          val incomingText = ACTIVITY.textVariable
          println("Incoming text: "+incomingText)

          // You can also set the value of this variable to be read from 
          // another fragment later
          ACTIVITY.textVariable = "Text set from TestFragmentOne"
      }
 }
```

Comment: This works correctly as long as you implement onSaveInstanceState to persist that mutable string, and restore it in onCreate if the savedInstanceState bundle is non-null.

Comment: I created BaseFragnent class and followed above approach but still getting null value

Comment: @EpicPandaForce true

Comment: @Test when are you getting null value? Reading the variable from your fragments? And what is null, the ACTIVITY or the textVariable?

Comment: println($incomingText) on the TestFragmentOne is null

Comment: @Test are you sure you're overriding onActivityCreated and NOT onViewCreated in your fragment? Because that would explain the null value as onViewCreated might be called before activity's onCreate

Comment: Created on OnActivity.

Comment: @Test this doesn't make much sense. Be careful of the methods you override in the fragments as Activity's onCreate precedes Fragment's onActivityCreated methods and this should work.

Otherwise follow EpicPandaForce's advice and insert arguments to your Fragment before replacing it in your replaceFragment method

Answer (score -2):

For this scenario I use a static Intent and transfer data through it as needed.

```
    static final Intent storageIntent = new Intent();

    storageIntent.putExtra("name", "value");
```

Comment: How to Retrieve this value from fragments?

Comment: This is wrong. The intent should not be static. This will be lost after process death and will lose its values. Use Intents for activities and use arguments bundle (setArguments) for Fragments.

Comment: It stays alive when placed in a public class, because it's also final. After the app died, the data isn't needed for exchange any more, I suppose.

Comment: You get the data with, for example: String s = storageIntent.getStringExtra("name");

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have tried already and its not working.

Comment: @JohannesSchidlowski you are wrong and should refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399

Comment: Ok, I use it every day and in all apps I have, and it works perfectly well across all activities, is painless and uses a "fragment" of memory compared to other solutions. However, if you use fragments and activities across different applications, then you are right, it would not work.

Comment: Here is a practical example, created from scratch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXLnl9Chc8w