# How to start a new instance of a class for every intent in android studio

Tags: java, android, instance

I'm creating an editor in `Android` and for every **type of** `ImageView` i'm creating a `.class`

The types of the `ImageViews` are the following:

```java
private Class<?> popups[] = {
Clock_pop_up.class, TV_kitchen_pop_up.class, Thermometer_pop_up.class, CoffeeMachine_pop_up.class, Fridge_pop_up.class, Oven_pop_up.class, Air_pop_up.class, TV_livingroom_pop_up.class
};
```

I have modified these classes with a `<style>` that for every `Intent` it's shown as a pop-up dialog

**The problem is this:**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), (Class<?>) popups[finalI]);
startActivity(intent);
```

It shows the pop-up correctly, although if a `.class` repeats it self on the grid then i have the same "settings" for every two or more same classes

**For Example**

Let's say i add a  `Clock_pop_up.class` and i set the "settings", **Hour** to 06 and **Minutes** to 05

[image]

Then i'll add a `Thermometer_pop_up.class` and set the "settings"

[image]

> **The Problem:** If i add another `Clock_pop_up.class` or `Thermometer_pop_up.class` , i'll get the previous set "settings"

[image]

I've already tried this:

- [Create new instance using `Class<?>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor?fbclid=IwAR1l5DX2IWLXCjFbj7olWS-smJ2W71PUPKhVFDdFj4H-T2jkLv-e-JxP1WQ) , but it didn't work for me.

Is there any other way i can create `instances` of a `.class` every time i put the `ImageView` on the grid? Is there any other workaround?

Edit: I have to mention i'm using `static` fields in `.class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding a `HashMap` Object into each `PopUp.class` mapping each time a new Object.

For example:

New Clock Object:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Clock implements Serializable {
    private String hour;
    private String minute;
    private String condition;

    public Clock(String hour, String minute,String condition) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.condition=condition;
    }

    public Clock() {
    }

    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(String minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "hour='" + hour + '\'' +
                ", minute='" + minute + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }
}
```

And at `Clock_pop_up.class` i create the `HashMap` Object like so:

```java
 public static  HashMap<String, Clock> currentObject = new HashMap<>();
```

So for each `PopUp.class` i have a `HashMap` for every `Object` on the GridLayout and afterwards i can collect all my `Objects` via the `HashMap`

Comment: Static map? It is unlikely that this will work correctly after process death. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399 to see how you can crash your app on your second screens.

Comment: I'm refreshing the static `HashMap` on the next `Intent`, haven't crashed yet

Comment: so if i deal with Low Memory i have to maybe use `SharedPrefs` instead?