# Custom data object saving its data when passed between fragments - android

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

I am using android jetpack navigation in my project. So I have an activity and multiple fragments. I realize that if I create an object in fragment a and pass it to fragment b when I change the object field value in fragment b and turn back to fragment a with onbackpressed() method the object in fragment a is not updated. However, if I pass the same object from fragment b to fragment c end change the object field value in fragment c and turn back to fragment b then the object data in fragment b is updated. So what is the difference here?

Fragment A

```
    Product prd  = new Product();
    prd.setId(Utils.getRandomString(6));

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT, prd);

    newPrd.setOnClickListener((v) -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_dashboard_to_productEditorFragment, bundle));
```

Fragment B

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  if (getArguments() != null) {
        product = getArguments().getParcelable(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT);
        if (product != null) {
            fillViews(product);
        }
    }}
 private void sendObjectToFragmentC() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (product!= null)
        bundle.putParcelable(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT, product);
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_productEditorFragment_to_tagSelectFragment, bundle);
}
```

Fragment C

```
  if (getArguments() != null) {
        product = getArguments().getParcelable(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT);
        if (product != null) {
            fillViews(product);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mostly that you're "lucky" when you mutate the object in place. After process death, the changes done in C would not reflect in B.

Comment: What you mean with process death, is it kill of fragment ? When does process death ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107399/2413303