# Android google maps v2 unknown error

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-fragments, api-key

well I try to make this sample at he developer page

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=tr#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

this is my java code:

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and xml code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

but if I try to do this on REAL DEVICE, Log cat says:

```
  02-13 17:28:59.327: W/dalvikvm(12793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410c02a0)
    02-13 17:28:59.327: E/AndroidRuntime(12793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-13 17:28:59.327: E/AndroidRuntime(12793): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.restroomgames.urfarehberi/com.restroomgames.urfarehberi.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
```

also:

```
 02-13 17:28:59.327: E/AndroidRuntime(12793): Caused by: 
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment 
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an
 empty constructor that is public
```

also:

```
    02-13 17:28:59.327: E/AndroidRuntime(12793): Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

---

This video helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fitjMdZ8jqM
I think The problem is Debug.keystore or google play service because I changed them, the problem vanished.

Also I wrote the solution on my webpage:

http://restroomgames.com/blog.php?ID=27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your using a wrong pattern for inflating.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.restroomgames.urfarehberi/com.restroomgames.urfarehberi.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragmen
```

Look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137231/2523005

Comment: maybe you will right but I can t fix it. I downloaded some tutorial and imported them. there are also some error: [2014-02-13 21:50:39 - GoogleMapsV2] Unable to resolve target 'android-12'
[2014-02-13 21:50:40 - GoogleMapsV2] Unable to resolve target 'android-12'
[2014-02-13 22:05:52 - actionbarsherlock] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'
[2014-02-13 22:05:52 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-02-13 22:06:14 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-02-13 22:06:15 - actionbarsherlock] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'

Comment: You only downloaded the tutorial? What tutorial did you use? Did you have the android sdk installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't test Google Maps in emulator. It does not have Google Play Services.

Comment: well I am using real device

Comment: Can you provide your manifest file? Or at least part related to Google Play services permissions.