# Error inflating class fragment while trying to use Google Maps

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to run simple demo app of Google Maps. I've referred standard article.

But I'm getting **Error inflating class fragment** exception.

I've updated mt manifest properly. Registered for Map API key. Install google-play-services and linked it to my current project. Extended my activity from FragmentActivity, still it doesn't work.

Am I doing anything wrong?

I also referred [Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment) but to no avail.
Any help appreciated.

My code is as follows:
*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.android.googlemapsdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(KIEL)
                    .title("Kiel")
                    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        } else {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to generate map",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.googlemapsdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.android.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAT9_V5YI-7CMf_Yta0Y_zeDfPZeH5XFL0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

to

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
```

If you have 11 you will be using `SupportMapFragment`. Consider this

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net

Looking at the link it is better to change to 12

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Also `getMap()` can return null. Better check the availability of google map services.

You are also missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in manifest file

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

You can also remove

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.android.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

and this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Made minSdkVersion as 15, extended from `FragmentActivity`, imported `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`, removed those lined from manifest, still same error :(

Comment: @GAMA extend `Activity`. No need for `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` is the base class for support based fragments. Since you will be not using `SupportMapFragment` there is no need to extend `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: So should I make 1)minSdkVersion as 15 & 2)remove those lined from manifest FROM ABOVE MENTIONED CODE IN QUESTION, that's it?

Comment: @GAMA Deleted the answer. You have choices. If you want to support gingerbreads and below, consider using `FragmentActivity` and `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: yes make it above 11. coz there are not many devices in the market that run on 11. yes those lines are not required. You need to extend Activity

Comment: @GAMA did you even try to read the docs the link i posted in my post??

Comment: After adding access_network_state permission and making minSdkVersion 12, it worked. Now, it's throwing map key authorization failure but that's a different issue, Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm going through 2nd article to set-up Map correctly, Cheers!

Comment: @GAMA you need to check the key in the google api console for that

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Because your `minsdk="11"`

also change this

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

to

```
 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

Comment: Do I have to extend from something else instead of `Activity`?