# ViewPagerIndicator library doesn't work in 4.4

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using `viewpagerindicator` library for circle indicator and it works great on `5.0(Lolipop), 6.0(Marshmallow)` but it crashes on `4.4(Kitkat)`.I've tried using dependency based on module by adding library project and using following option but none of them works on 4.4

```
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
```

Here's the log.

```
2-29 18:27:22.992  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0177
12-29 18:27:22.992  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator.setViewPager, referenced from method com.kicksexchange.fragments.ProductDetail.updateUI
12-29 18:27:23.002  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 62723: Lcom/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator;.setViewPager (Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager;)V
12-29 18:27:23.002  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0271
12-29 18:27:23.072  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/ProductDetail﹕ onCreate Product Detail Fragment
12-29 18:27:23.072  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/ProductDetail﹕ 205
12-29 18:27:23.072  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/ProductDetail﹕ Nike Sports Shoes
12-29 18:27:23.192  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-29 18:27:23.192  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42046d58)
12-29 18:27:23.242  32182-32182/com.kicksexchange E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kicksexchange, PID: 32182
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.kicksexchange.fragments.ProductDetail.onCreateView(ProductDetail.java:152)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kicksexchange-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kicksexchange-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.kicksexchange.fragments.ProductDetail.onCreateView(ProductDetail.java:152)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote?

Comment: Please use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager instead of android.app.ViewPager.Add compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0' if need.

Comment: Are you using multidex?

Comment: Yes multidex is enabled

Comment: finally it worked with multidex configuration.@Jozua