# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

i have a app that has firebase.
so i get crash reporting
but i don't know why it happen and how to fix.

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.homers.health_coach/com.homers.health_coach.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2540)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2599)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:174)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5748)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
arrow_drop_down


Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:719)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:761)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:769)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:751)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:751)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:498)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:398)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:354)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:109)
com.homers.health_coach.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:58)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5600)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1093)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2504)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2599)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:174)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5748)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
arrow_drop_down


Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.homers.health_coach.fragment_workout_list did not create a view.
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView (FragmentManager.java:2314)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView (FragmentController.java:111)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:314)
android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView (BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:79)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:695)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:761)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:769)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:751)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:751)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:498)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:398)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:354)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:109)
com.homers.health_coach.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:58)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5600)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1093)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2504)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2599)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:174)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5748)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

here is layout xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.homers.health_coach.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.homers.health_coach.fragment_community"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_community" />

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.homers.health_coach.fragment_workout_list"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_workout_list" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

58line is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

please tell me why happens and how to fix it..
help me please. 
thanks:)

Comment: If you are running your code for API level <11, use FragmentActivity instead of extending Activity

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168223/2623882)
will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView()` in your `fragment_workout_list` returns `null` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you probably didn't return a view in the `onCreateView` method of your `fragment_workout_list`:

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.homers.health_coach.fragment_workout_list did not create a view.

Make sure you have something similiar to this in your `fragment_workout_list`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container, false);
}
```

Comment: thanks answer. :)
there is the same code in my fragement_workout_list.java file.

nomaly there is no error. but when finished app and after run again it happen um....why like that?...

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the orientation in the Linear Layout which i suppose should be vertical in your case. As far as i can see, the error clearly states that there's something wrong with the xml file and hence it cannot be inflated