# InflateException with Android <fragment>

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments

I am following the steps of an example in a book and I get several errors when debugging with the emulator:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity, PID: 2995
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity/activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
>                         at activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListActivity.onCreate(TaskListActivity.java:25)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>                      Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListFragment that is not a Fragment
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
>                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5286)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144) 
>                         at activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListActivity.onCreate(TaskListActivity.java:25) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606) 
>                         at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582) 
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5286) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144) 
>                         at activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListActivity.onCreate(TaskListActivity.java:25) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

The related java file is (TaskListFragment.java):

```js
package activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; 


import  activity.tasks.dummies.com.adapter.TaskListAdapter;


public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment
    {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TaskListAdapter adapter;

        public TaskListFragment()
        {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            adapter = new TaskListAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_list, container, false);
            final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_list, container, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            return v;
        }

    }
```

And my XML layout (activity_task_list.xml):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Toolbar
        style="?android:actionBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_task_list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The line 15 that is mentioned in the error is in the xml in < fragment

I'm beginner on Android and I do not know how to fix it.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Thanks

Also there is another class (TaskListActivity.java):

```js
package activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

    public class TaskListActivity extends Activity
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
            setActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your package name?

Comment: I think you pasted your XML twice, not your Java and XML.

Comment: The java file is TaskListFragment.java and xml is fragment_task_list.xml

Comment: XML inflation errors are notoriously nondescript, but a common mistake is mixing up default and support fragments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: I fix the error of pasting xml 2 times in this  thread

Comment: El package is:
activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity;

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: Ok. I update the question

Comment: I think the main issue here is this line from the stack `Trying to instantiate a class activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListFragment that is not a Fragment` , let me do some digging :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    class ="activity.tasks.dummies.com.tasklistactivity.TaskListFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_task_list"/>
```

in you Activity class:

```
    public class TaskListActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
        setActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }
}
```

and `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

Comment: Nop. The same problem

Comment: in your activity flle ..where u call the `fragment` should extend `FragmentActivity` not `Activity`

Comment: There is another class:

public class TaskListActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
        setActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }
}

Comment: try `TaskListActivity extends FragmentActivity`

Comment: also make sure u import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

Comment: I updated the question. Yes, there is your suggestion:

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Your suggestions are gray (disabled)

Comment: you need to extend `FragmentActivity` activity class then the import will work

Comment: Also `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is for ur `TaskListFragment ` class

Comment: I update the question android.support.v4.app.Fragment is OK in TaskListFragment.java (import android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Comment: It worked with extends FragmentActivity. 

Thanks for the help.

Could you tell me why it is?

Comment: `FragmentActivity` has the feature to statically inflate a `<fragemnt>` tag from xml...but activity does not..see this link for detail clarification:https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments