# Why am i getting this error in logcat (Android)?

Tags: android

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: org.example.easyparking, PID: 6371
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.example.easyparking/org.example.easyparking.MapActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML
>   file line #0: Error inflating class fragment

This is my mapactivity

```
    package org.example.easyparking;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

    public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    if(googleServicesAvailable()){

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        initMap();
    }else{
        //No Google Map Layout
    }
}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public boolean googleServicesAvailable(){
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
}
}
```

This is menifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.example.easyparking">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<permission android:name="org.example.easyparking.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="org.example.easyparking.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity">

    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDGpV3ndPQ1Z4zf1nXi5AW1c7jGPL1La7Q"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>



</application>
</manifest>
```

This is the first activity

```
    package org.example.easyparking;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Make sure that your location is turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent newacti = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(newacti);
        }
    });

    Button button_parking_owner = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button_parking_owner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent newacti = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(newacti);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your activity and fragment xml layout

Comment: problem is in activity_map.xml of your map activity. please check line number 0 of activity_map.xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: Your `MapActivity` since it uses `fragments` should extend the `FragmentActivity` class

Comment: I assume `googleServicesAvailable()` is returning false which is making the `else` statement to be executed which is empty at the moment

Answer (score 0):

In your `MapActivity` you are checking if `googleServicesAvailable()` is available and if not you are not providing a default content to render

```
if(googleServicesAvailable()){

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        initMap();
    }else{
        //No Google Map Layout
    }
```

try creating a basic layout to render that says something like **No Google Map**
i.e you should have something like

```
if(googleServicesAvailable()){

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        initMap();
    }else{
        //No Google Map Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.no_activity_map);
    }
```

then create a `no_activity_map` layout