# Google Maps - Error Inflating SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

As stated above im trying to implement googlemaps into my app and keep getting "Error inflating class fragment" error at the beggining of the map fragment xml. Here's the xml tag in which the fragment is situated:

```
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_map_display"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_text_edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/activity_main_search_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the error message I've been getting(line 21 is the beginning of the fragment tag):

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.robert.pkpwayfinder, PID: 3947
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.robert.pkpwayfinder/com.example.robert.pkpwayfinder.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML
> file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>         at com.example.robert.pkpwayfinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:55)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: We also need the rest of the stacktrace, and whatever tag that "relevant piece of code" belongs to.

Comment: Also, post your `LogCat` error

Comment: done @TheWanderer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: please show your view where you implement map fragment

Answer (score 0):

Being a fragment, this component can be added to an activity's layout file simply with the XML below [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment):

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Replace this line:

> android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

And make sure you added dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
 android:class"com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 Change it like this :

 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```