# Error inflating class Fragment in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a fragment that will chang everytime I pick another item from a listview. when my file is complying I get this error.

(part of) my code:

```
public class SongListActivity : AppCompatActivity, ListView.IOnItemClickListener, ListView.IOnItemLongClickListener
    {
....
AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        infoFragment infoFragment1;  
....
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {    
....  
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SongList);
            fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
             infoFragment1 = new infoFragment();
            transaction.Add(Resource.Id.info, infoFragment1, "tag1");
            transaction.Commit();
          }
....
```

this is the XML file of this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background3"
    
   >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1" />

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/evSearch"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="40dp"  
        android:hint="  "  
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"  
        android:background="#FDF3FA"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"   
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentinfo"
         />

   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@id/info"
         />

        <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="#dddddd"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    />
       
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the fragment's class

```
public class infoFragment : Fragment
    {
        View view;
        Communicator c;
        TextView tvTitle, tvArtists;
        ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5, iv6, iv7, iv8, iv9, iv10;
        List<Chord> list, chordlist;
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.Debug("app", "OnCreate fragment");
            // Create your fragment here
            list = new List<Chord>();
            chordlist = new List<Chord>();
            chordlist = MainActivity.chordList;
        }
        public infoFragment()
        {

        }
        public override void OnAttach(Context context)
        {
            base.OnAttach(context);

            if (context.GetType() == typeof(AppCompatActivity)){
                c = (Communicator)context;
                Log.Debug("Freddie", "Mercury");
            }
            else Log.Debug("Freddie", "mmmmm");

        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_info, container, false);
            tvTitle = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvFragment);
            tvArtists = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvArtist);
            iv1 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv1);
            iv2 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv2);
            iv3 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv3);
            iv4 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv4);
            iv5 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv5);
            iv6 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv6);
            iv7 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv7);
            iv8 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv8);
            iv9 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv9);
            iv10 = (ImageView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.iv10);
            return view;

        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Log.Debug("app", "OnActivityCreated");
        }
        public List<Chord> convertStringToList()// פעולה שתחזיר רשימה של פריטים מטיפוס אקורד, לאחר המרה של מחרוזת
        {
            List<Chord> l = new List<Chord>();// רשימת אקורדים שאליה נכניס את כל הפריטים
            string ch = "";// משתנה מטיפוס מחרוזת שאליו נשרשר תווים 
            string cl = "";
            cl = AddNewSongActivity.cl;
            for (int i = 0; i < cl.Length; i++)// לולאה שתרוץ כאורך המחרוזת
            {
                while (cl[i] != '/')//לולאה שתרוץ עד שיופיע הסימן המפריד שקבעתי
                {
                    ch += cl[i];//שרשור של תת המחרוזת למחרוזת
                }
                foreach (var item in chordlist)//לולאה שתרוץ על כל פריט ברשימת האקורדים 
                {
                    if (item.getChordName() == ch)//אם שם הפריט תואם את המחרוזת בדיוק
                        l.Add(item);  //נוסיף את הפריט לרשימה
                }
                ch = ""; // אתחול הערך של המחרוזת כדי שנוכל לעשות את הפעולות האלו על כל המחרוזת

            }
            return l;//החזרת הרשימה
        }
        public override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            Log.Debug("app", "OnStart activity");
        }
        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Log.Debug("app", "OnResume activity");

        }
        public void displaySong(Song s)
        {
            tvTitle.Text = s.getSongName();
            tvArtists.Text = s.GetArtistName();
            list = convertStringToList();
            displayChords(s);

        }
```

I was trying to compile. When I try it, I get "error inflating class Fragment" and I can't understand why.I hope it is detailed enough:/. I would love to get your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the SongListActivity inherit from the FragmentActivity, such as:

```
using AndroidX.Fragment.App;

public class SongListActivity : FragmentActivity, ListView.IOnItemClickListener, ListView.IOnItemLongClickListener
    {
....
AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        infoFragment infoFragment1;  
....
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {    
....  
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SongList);
            fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
             infoFragment1 = new infoFragment();
            transaction.Add(Resource.Id.info, infoFragment1, "tag1");
            transaction.Commit();
          }
....
```

For more information, you can refer to the official document about [using Fragment in the xamarin.android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/implementing-with-fragments/walkthrough?tabs=windows) and the old case about [Error inflating class fragment in the native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment).

Answer (score 0):

You are really trying to do this the hard way. Why not use Google's NavigationComponent (SingleActvity/multiple fragments) where you don't have to be concerned with Fragment Transactions?

Take a look at the modern way of writing either Xamarin.Android or android-net7 apps at https://github.com/gmck - specifically the NavigationGraph series.