# Access button in MainActivity from fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have 5 destinations in my app in order to make easy for the user to navigate between them, I have had used bottom navigation and fragment.
All may destinations have a common floating action button, which will perform other task from one to other, in order to access it from a specific fragment I declared the button as public in the MainActivity, and access it in the fragments like this: `(requireActivity() as MainActivity).fab.`
this is work with no problem, here is the problem I faced, when I set the fragment as home fragment and try to access the button the same why I do with other fragment I have this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.example.invoicegenerator, PID: 6249
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.invoicegenerator/com.example.invoicegenerator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.invoicegenerator:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.example.invoicegenerator:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
```

here is the method I create to access button

```
// Access the button in the MainActivity.
private fun accessMainButton(): FloatingActionButton {
    return (requireActivity() as MainActivity).fab
}
```

It worked for all fragment except the home fragment,
I had tried most solutions here on stack over flow nothing worked.

I'm using Kotlin to program the android app.

Comment: Please share the code where this error originates from.

Comment: @tomerpacific sure I will edit my question now :)

Comment: You should show your logic on how and when you call the `accessMainButton` inside the erring fragment.

Comment: Show the rest of the call stacktrace - the crash is not because it doesn't find the button, it's whatever the button click is doing that's crashing.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: @dominicoder exactly, can you provide me a sample of code for such stuff?

Comment: There is no "sample code" for _you_ to provide the rest of _your_ stacktrace. You showed us _three_ lines of the crash. That's not enough. Get the full stacktrace and update your question. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug